# Java Javadoc include Private

Tags: java, include, javadoc, private

I would like to generate javadocs for my application and i would also like to include private members.

I have found the following in the [Javadoc documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#javadocoptions)

```
       -private
           Shows all classes and members.
```

Could you please help me by giving an example of the execution of this?

It should be something like: `javadoc -private ...`. I need to know how to provide the root directory and destination directory for the generated html doc files.

thank you.

**EDIT:** i found a way to generate javadoc from NetBeans 6.8. this is as follows:

NetBeans Java projects typically have a parameter for this in the project’s properties section. You can right-click the project name in the Projects Window and select Properties. In the Project Properties window that appears, the Documenting node contains a checkbox field labeled ‘Include Private and Package Private Members’.

i found this [here](http://pronetbeans.com/?p=40)

seems to generate docs as desired. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the command line, it says

```
javadoc [options] [packagenames] [sourcefiles] [@files]
```

So it would be something like:

```
javadoc -private -d output/directory -sourcepath src/java
```

But you may also take a look to the [javadoc documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#argumentfiles) and this [section](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#processingofsourcefiles).

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the man-page?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javadoc.html

It contains a section of simple examples.

Try this for instance

```
javadoc -private -d /home/html -sourcepath /home/src
```