# JavaDoc: private fields and methods

Tags: java, javadoc, private

What JavaDoc tags should I use in private fields and methods in order to generate javaDoc descriptions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [Java Javadoc include Private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101339/java-javadoc-include-private); you still use the standard JavaDoc comment form but you must instruct the JavaDoc tool to generate the documentation for private members using the `-private` switch.