# Why can't I quote private field, method on javadoc in intellij-idea 2018.3.5?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

A few days ago, I upgrade intellij-idea to version 2018.3.5,183.5912.21 on my computer. And I find this version isn't allowed to quote private filed, method on javadoc. That bother me a lot. In previous version, I can quote private field, method on javadoc.

For exmaple,

```
public class Foo {

  private static final int CONSTANT = 1;

  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  //ignore getter, setter, toString...

  private void doSth() {
  }
}
```

And I write javadoc on somewhere I use Foo,
 [image: stackoverflow-idea-cannot-quote-private-field-method.png]

How can I change the config of intellij-idea? Or is there other way to write javadoc?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655737/javadoc-private-fields-and-methods

Answer (score 7):

Please go to *Java | Javadoc | Declaration has problems in Javadoc references* inspection and uncheck the *Report inaccessible symbols option*. So the references will not be highlighted as inaccessible.
[image]

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using IntelliJ, but I can tell you that javadoc is created by the JDK. The IDE just makes the request easier. You can create private javadoc.

For IntelliJ just read this tutorial:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-code-documentation.html

You just have to move the slider from package to private to generate it.

Note: even if you don't generate it is still good to put javadoc in your private field and method. That's a good way to document and make code more  understandable.