# Netbeans javadoc skips methods

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

Running javadocs on a web project and it's skipping all but 4 of the methods in the servlet file.  It generates the docs for doGet(), doPost(), processRequest(), and getServletInfo() but ignores the other 14 methods I have in there.

For example:

```
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

 /**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Notifies user of an error in the java code
 *
 * @param e Exception generated
 * @return HTML as String
 */
private String returnError(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    String returnString = "<html><body><h1>" + e.getMessage() + "</h1></body></html>";
    return returnString;
}
```

It generates the doGet() and doPost(), but I get nothing for returnError().

It doesn't do this with any other class in the project.

Comment: maybe because the method is `private`?

Comment: Related: [Java Javadoc include Private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101339/java-javadoc-include-private)

Comment: LOL..maybe I should just delete this question out of embarrassment?  :)

Comment: Or maybe I'll just leave it so that others can benefit from my misfortune.